update the postgres table in fast Api with sqlalchemy and pydantic
given below is my code is written in the past Api here I want to update the table row in the progress but I am facing this error

Argument of type "dict[str, Any]" cannot be assigned to parameter "values" of type "Dict[_DMLColumnArgument, Any]" in function "update"
  "dict[str, Any]" is incompatible with "Dict[_DMLColumnArgument, Any]"
    Type parameter "_KT@dict" is invariant, but "str" is not the same as "_DMLColumnArgument"PylancereportArgumentType

on this part update(updated_post.model_dump(exclude_unset=True)

the pydantic and the sql alchemy model is the same but still getting he error 




from fastapi import FastAPI,HTTPException,status,Depends,Response
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session 
from . import models,schema
from .database import engine,get_db

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)



@app.put("/post/{id}")
def update_post(id:int,updated_post:schema.CreatePost,db:Session=Depends(get_db)):
    
    post_query=db.query(models.Post).filter(models.Post.id==id)
    
    post=post_query.first()
    
    if not post:
        
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,detail=f"post with id {id} is not available ")

    post_query.update(updated_post.model_dump(exclude_unset=True),synchronize_session=False)
    db.commit()
    print("====data",post_query)
    return []
        

from pydantic import BaseModel
from datetime import datetime

class basePost(BaseModel):
    title:str
    content:str
    is_publish:bool=True
    
class CreatePost(basePost):
    pass

class Post(basePost):
    id:int
    created_at:datetime
    
    class Config:
        from_attributes=True
    

from .database import Base
from sqlalchemy import String,Integer,Boolean,Column
from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import TIMESTAMP
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import text



class Post(Base):
    __tablename__="postal"
    
    id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True,nullable=False)
    title=Column(String,nullable=False)
    content=Column(String,nullable=False)
    is_publish=Column(Boolean,server_default='True')
    created_at=Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True),nullable=False,server_default=text('now()'))

I want to update the table entry but getting the type mismatch error I am quite new to python and fast API
to resolve this I found 2 solutions
1- update_data = {column.name: getattr(updated_post, column.name) for column in models.Post._table_.columns}
2-
update_data = {
    column.name: getattr(updated_post, column.name)
    for column in models.Post.__table__.columns
    if hasattr(updated_post, column.name)
}

in the 1st solution there might be error if in the update we don't provide all the values but 2nd one is more complicated
can anyone help me to find the any better solution for this
